# MariaDB - update all rows with value of the previous + constant

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mariadb

I have the following example table:

[image]

I want to make it work this way - I add constant to every row p6 but row grows with value of the previos one + constant.
For example if I decide that the constant is 10 table should look like:

[image]

```
UPDATE table t SET t.p6 = (SELECT t1.P6 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.id=t.id-1) + 10
```

but it is making p6 of the first row with id=1 NULL and the rest is not working. How I can do it with ignoring the first row which has the correct value and updating just the following?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `join` and window functions:

```
update t join
       (select t.*,
               row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum,
               first_value(p6) over (order by id) as first_p6
        from t
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set p6 = (seqnum - 1) * 5 + first_p6
    where seqnum > 1;
```

In older versions you can use variables:

```
set @p6 := 0;

update t
    set p6 = (@p6 := (case when id = 1 then p6 else @p6 + 5 end))
    order by id;
```

Comment: on row  set p6 = (seqnum - 1) * 5 + first_p6   you probably mean +5 not *5

Comment: it is adding 5 to the second row but then it only adds +1 to next rows...